# Grails g:render a template (or render a div) onClick event

Tags: html, list, templates, grails, render

I am creating a hierarchical list with expandable/ collapsible list items. When a user clicks on a list item to expand it a table pops up with some info. Right now, grails is rendering all of the tables when the page is loaded. However, I only want the tables to be loaded when the list item is clicked. I am using partial templates to house the table html and using

```
<g:render>
```

To render them. Is there a way to convert the code I am going to post so that the div with class="list" to only load on click? If not, is there a way to call the g:render tag only on click?

```
<g:each in="${group2List}" var="item">
            <li class="liClosed"><b>
                    ${item}
            </b> <%= Application.findAllWhere((group2): item, (group1): group).size() %>
                <ul>
                    <div class="list">
                        <table id="portfolio">
                            <g:render template="tableHeader" />
                            <g:render template="applicationRow"
                                collection="${Application.findAllWhere((group2): item, (group1): group)}"
                                var="applicationInstance" />
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ul></li>
            <br />
</g:each>
```

So, Is there a way to add an onClick event for the li that renders that div class="list" only on click? Or a way to call those g:renders onClick while keeping them inside the ul.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The reason I am attempting to do this, is because the current method is extremely slow and the page takes a long time to laod

Comment: g:render executes on server side while onClick on client side (browser) you are mixing them both, I would say clear your concepts.

You can use ajax to load the content of list divs when a list item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Like @sudhir commented above, you can't load server-side content into client-side content. The grails tags are rendered once the page is loaded. But you can use ajax to load the data in the server and render a partial template with the new data in it. That's exactly what you need. You can check out [this](http://www.craigburke.com/blog/2011/01/01/grails-ajax-list-with-paging-and-sorting/) link that may fit your needs.